# Is there any other way to send notification messages to a user without firebase?

Tags: firebase, push-notification, observer-pattern

I am currently working on an app which will be used to send important messages as fast as possible to multiple people.

I found out that there is such a thing like firebase with which it is possible to send messages from a custom server to iOS and android devices.

But I need a solid and secure solution and firebase is therefore only my plan b. I would prefer a custom solution.

How can I achieve that a message will be sent to a client without firebase? I do not want the client to check for a new message every x seconds. That would be a waste of data. The triggering must come from the server. Can this be achieved using the observer pattern?

Comment: What you're asking to do is exactly what firebase does; it's not a polling situation, the server notifies clients about events. *I do not want the client to check for a new message every x seconds* <- called 'polling' and not what Firebase does. You should take the time to read up about Firebase as it sounds like what you need [Welcome to Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs)

Answer (score 1):

Firebase is a online datebase. If you try to choose a db for your app, you can choose insted MongoDB, which have a online version of db.

Comment: okay, but is it possible to create a custom push service and an efficient demon on the client device to check for new messages on a completly own system setup?

Comment: Firebase has 18 or so products, 2 of which are databases. OP seems to be asking about Firebase Cloud Messaging, not about its databases.